# Why I can't publish to Azure Cloud Services through Visual Studio?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to deploy to Azure Cloud Services an Azure Cloud Project but I only can do it creating a "Package" (right click on the project/Package..) and then uploading it at the Azure website. It makes me upload all the project every time when I need to deploy any change. 
My user was set as an Owner into the Azure account by an other Owner and I was crate the Cloud Services "item" into the Azure portal.
Why I can't do the publish process through Visual Studio? I think it will be more easy and don't need to upload all the project every time.

- Azure SDK v2.9
- Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.40518.2

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the version of the Azure SDK and Azure VS tools you have installed? Also, you likely already tried this, but the drop down for subscription are you sure it's the same selected subscription as where you created the Cloud Service via the portal?

Comment: Yes sure, I've updated with this info and yes it's the same subscription because is the only one that I have.

Comment: This really looks like a question for Azure support (specifically a billing support question, which is free), since it's telling you there's no access to Cloud Services in your subscription (which doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Ok I have made the same request to Azure Service. Let's see what happens. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally talking with customer service of Azure (billing support as  suggested @David Makogon), setting rights of co-admin or administrator did the trick. It seems that setting up my account with an Owner rights isn't enough to publish to Azure Cloud Services through Visual Studio.

[How to add co-admin to Azure (Microsoft Link)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/)